# BitVector in Z3 - functions for different bits

Tags: z3, smt

I have this code to check if other elements are contained sets.

```
;; All is encoding the set that contains {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
(define-const All (_ BitVec 6) #b111111)
;; Empty is encoding the empty set
(define-const Empty (_ BitVec 6) #b000000)

(define-fun LT_l ((S (_ BitVec 6)) (l (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    ;; True if for all x in S x < l
    (= (bvand (bvshl All l) S) Empty))

(define-fun GT_l ((l (_ BitVec 6)) (S (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    ;; True if for all x in S l < x
    (= (bvand (bvnot (bvshl All l)) S) Empty))

(define-fun is_in ((e (_ BitVec 6)) (S (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
   ;; True if e is an element of the "set" S.
   (not (= (bvand (bvshl (_ bv1 6) e) S) Empty)))

(define-fun is_minimal ((e (_ BitVec 6)) (S (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    (and (is_in e S)
         (= (bvand (bvsub (bvshl (_ bv1 6) e) (_ bv1 6)) S) Empty)))

(define-fun LT ((L0 (_ BitVec 6)) (L1 (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    ; True if forall x in L0 and forall y in L1, x < y
    (or (= L0 Empty)
        (= L1 Empty)
        (exists ((min (_ BitVec 6))) (and (is_minimal min L1) (LT_l L0 min)))))


(declare-const consoleLock (_ BitVec 6))
(declare-const l1 (_ BitVec 6))
(declare-const l2 (_ BitVec 6)) 

( assert (distinct consoleLock l1 l2 ) )

( assert (or (= l1 (_ bv0 6)) (= l1 (_ bv1 6)) (= l1 (_ bv2 6)) (= l1 (_ bv4 6)) ))
( assert (or (= l2 (_ bv0 6)) (= l2 (_ bv1 6)) (= l2 (_ bv2 6)) (= l2 (_ bv4 6)) ))
( assert (or (= consoleLock (_ bv0 6)) (= consoleLock (_ bv1 6)) (= consoleLock (_ bv2 6)) (= consoleLock (_ bv4 6)) ))


(declare-const L4 (_ BitVec 6))
(declare-const L1 (_ BitVec 6))
(declare-const L0 (_ BitVec 6))
(declare-const L5 (_ BitVec 6))


(assert (LT_l L0 l1))
(assert (LT L0 L1))
(assert (GT_l L1 l1))

(assert (LT_l L4 l2))
(assert (LT L4 L5))
(assert (GT_l L5 l2))

(declare-const T1 (_ BitVec 6))
(assert (= T1 l1))
(assert (LT_l T1 l2))

(declare-const T2 (_ BitVec 6))
(assert (= T2 l2))
(assert (LT_l T2 l1))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

My problem is that you want to use this code also for vectors with 8-bit and 16-bit but it doesn't work.

For example, if I replace all (_ BitVec 6) by (_ BitVec 8), the above code does not work well, because the result should be unsat but it sat.

As if to 6-bit vectors works well.

How can I make it work for different sizes of bit vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We also have to adjust the constant occurring in the example: `#b111111`, `#b000000`, `(_ bv1 6)`, etc. That being said, SMT-LIB 2.0 format is not very convenient for writing parametric problems. I think the programmatic API is easier to use to encode parametric problems.
Here is the same example encoded using the Z3 Python API. It is also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/8L77). We can change the size of the bit-vectors by replacing `SZ = 6` with `SZ = 8` or `SZ = 16`.

```py
def All(sz):
    return BitVecVal(2**sz - 1, sz)

def Empty(sz):
    return BitVecVal(0, sz)

def LT_l(S, l):
    sz = S.size()
    return (All(sz) << l) & S == Empty(sz)

def GT_l(l, S):
    sz = S.size()
    return (~(All(sz) << l)) & S == Empty(sz)    

def is_in(e, S):
    sz = S.size()
    one = BitVecVal(1, sz)
    return (1 << e) & S != Empty(sz)

def is_minimal(e, S):
    sz = S.size()
    return And(is_in(e, S), ((1 << e) - 1) & S == Empty(sz))

def LT(L0, L1):
    sz = L0.size()
    min = BitVec('min', sz)
    return Or(L0 == Empty(sz), L1 == Empty(sz), Exists([min], And(is_minimal(min, L1), LT_l(L0, min))))

SZ=6
consoleLock = BitVec('consoleLock', SZ)
l1 = BitVec('l1', SZ)
l2 = BitVec('l2', SZ)    

s = Solver()
s.add(Distinct(consoleLock, l1, l2))
s.add(Or(l1 == 0, l1 == 1, l1 == 2, l1 == 4))
s.add(Or(l2 == 0, l2 == 1, l2 == 2, l2 == 4))
s.add(Or(consoleLock == 0, consoleLock == 1, consoleLock == 2, consoleLock == 4))

L4 = BitVec('L4', SZ)
L1 = BitVec('L1', SZ)
L0 = BitVec('L0', SZ)
L5 = BitVec('L5', SZ)

s.add(LT_l(L0, l1))
s.add(LT(L0, L1))
s.add(GT_l(L1, l1))
s.add(LT_l(L4, l2))
s.add(LT(L4, L5))
s.add(GT_l(L5, l2))

T1 = BitVec('T1', SZ)
s.add(T1 == l1)
s.add(LT_l(T1, l2))

T2 = BitVec('T2', SZ)
s.add(T2 == l2)
s.add(LT_l(T2, l1))

print s.check()
```

Comment: thanks. SMT-LIB 2.0 format is not very convenient for writing parametric problems but it is possible without phyton, only SMT-LIB 2.0 format? If is possible how can I do?

Comment: We can't do it in SMT-LIB 2.0. Note that, Z3 has bindings for other programming languages (e.g., C, C++, Java, C#, etc). So, you can port the python code to any of these programming languages. Another option is to write a program that generates the SMT-LIB 2.0 file. Given an input N, the program would generate a SMT file for bit-vectors of size N.

Comment: Well, I was trying to do the second option, but the Z3 code I posted above does not work for all sizes, even just changing (_ BitVec 6) by (_ BitVec 8), #b111111 by #b11111111 and #b000000 by #b00000000. Even so it is not possible?

Comment: It should work. What was the problem? Could you provide a link for the generated file for Bit-vectors of size 8?

Comment: For example, for 16-bit does not work. It is also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/TlnD). Since the result should be unsat.

Comment: In the 6-bit version (in our question), you say that `l1`, `l2` and `consoleLock` are `0`, `1`, `2` or `4`. In the 16-bit version, you say they are `4`, `8` or `16`.

Comment: So I can not use these values​​? I need use 0,1,2,4,8 and 16 in 16-bit version.

Comment: The `16` is problematic for the 16-bit version. If we represent a set using a 16-bit value, then the sets can only contain values in `[0, 15]`. To have `16` as an element, we need to encode a set using at least 17 bits. Here is your example using `15` instead of `16`: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/HBuG

Comment: Of course it can only go up to 15. But if I remove 16 the result is sat, but should be unsat. http://rise4fun.com/Z3/aHup

Comment: Why? the model returned by Z3 satisfies all constraints (aka assertions). Which constraint/assertion do you think was not satisfied?